# How to run the next statement if the cell value is blank in EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba

> I Have a requirement to fill a web form using VBA. In a input data sheet Column F,G,H has few cell are blank.
>   I want to skip those blank cells and move to next statement without showing any error.
>   I have mentioned the VBA SCRIPT which I have created.

If someone help me to fix this i will feel very glad.

**From the following I want to skip the blank cells and go for next statement. Column ( F, G, H)**[image]

```
Sub copy_project_loop()

Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim SHELL_OBJECT
SHELL_OBJECT = "WScript.Shell"
Set objShell = CreateObject(SHELL_OBJECT)


IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "URL"

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop


    Set Doc = IE.document

    ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
      NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

      ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
      For intRow = 2 To NumRows

    Doc.getElementById("txtTimeStudyNbr").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A" & intRow).Value
    Doc.getElementById("Search").Click

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Doc.getElementById("lstQualifierTypes").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("E1").Value
    Doc.getElementById("Search").Click

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Doc.getElementById("lstQualifiers").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("E" & intRow).Value
    Doc.getElementById("ADD").Click

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Doc.getElementById("lstQualifierTypes").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("F1").Value
    Doc.getElementById("Search").Click

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Doc.getElementById("lstQualifiers").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("F" & intRow).Value
    Doc.getElementById("ADD").Click

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Doc.getElementById("lstQualifierTypes").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("G1").Value
    Doc.getElementById("Search").Click

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Doc.getElementById("lstQualifiers").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("G" & intRow).Value
    Doc.getElementById("ADD").Click

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Doc.getElementById("lstQualifierTypes").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("H1").Value
    Doc.getElementById("Search").Click

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Doc.getElementById("lstQualifiers").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("H" & intRow).Value
    Doc.getElementById("ADD").Click
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: You could test if the cell contains data and execute the statements only if they do. Use `If ... Then ... End If`

Comment: Thanks  i tried with 'IF... Then...End If' now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the IsEmpty function to check if the cell is blank.

If IsEmpty(Range("F3").Value) = True Then

Comment: I Tried this 'If IsEmpty(Range("F3").Value) = True Then' it is working perfectly thank you so much.